# How to check if extra property in log4net is empty or not

Tags: log4net, log4net-appender

I am using extra property which has to be logged into database at the time of exception.
Please check at this link for extra property usage.
https://www.codeproject.com/articles/140911/log4net-tutorial

I want to add a check in webconfig if that property is not initialized do something otherwise if that property is initialized do something else.
How to do that?

From comment:

> log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["Property1"] = someval; I am setting this property in some cases. But when I use %property{Property1} it displays values for cases which I have set. But for those cases where I have not specified values it logs (null) into database column. How to avoid null value and add blank space?

Comment: Please show **your** code instead of linking to a tutorial and properly describe what you are trying to do.

Comment: @stuartd: log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["Property1"] = someval;
I am setting this property in some cases.
But when I use %property{Property1} it displays values for cases which I have set. But for those cases where I have not specified values it logs (null) into database column. How to avoid null value and add blank space?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [NullText property.](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/P_log4net_Util_SystemInfo_NullText.htm)

> Use this value to indicate a null has been encountered while outputting a string representation of an item.
>
> The default value is (null). This value can be overridden by specifying a value for the log4net.NullText appSetting in the application's .config file.

You can set this in config:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="log4net.NullText" value="" />
</appSettings>
```

Or in code:

```
log4net.Util.SystemInfo.NullText = string.Empty;
```

Note that [if you are using an old version of log4net then the value has to be a single space rather than empty.](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-55)

Comment: This is the answer to your current question. If you have another question, ask another question.

Comment: Stuartd i am using latest (2.0.8) version of log4net and i have set above mentioned app setting but still getting (null) in log instead of empty string. don't wanted to set it into code

Comment: @KamranShahid you should ask a new question

Comment: Ok.
Sure Stuart